# swiping ViewPager to right or left causes timing problem in self-running slideshow

Tags: java, android, timer, android-viewpager, handler

I created a slideshow with ViewPager and schedule 4 seconds for delay and executing next slide. I wanna when swiping it manually to left or right, it pauses and wait for 4 seconds then go to next slide, but manually swiped slide dismissed by timer and automatically go to ongoing slide before 4 seconds. I searched stackoverflow and internet but not found any solution. Here is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager_id"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_id" />
.
.
.
</RelativeLayout>
```

in MainActivity.java:

```
ViewPager viewPager;
SlideShowAdapter adapter;
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;
Timer timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager_id);
    adapter = new SlideShowAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);        

    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            if (i==adapter.images.length-1){
                i=0;
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(i,true);
            }else {
                i++;
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(i,true);
            }
        }
    };

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(runnable);
        }
    },4000,4000);
}
```

}

Comment: when next slide you should restart or call again runnable

Comment: @PouriaHemati tanx for answering but what method is for swiping to next slide? how i cancel thread and restart it again?